# Find the first three words that start with c, have a double-e (ee) somewhere in the word and end with t?

Tags: shell, unix

So far I tried this

```
[suakhand@ ~]$ cat words | grep -E '^c.*(.{2}).*\1.*t$' | head -3
```

But I am not sure how to find the three words with double ee.

Comment: Why not simply writing `ee`? BTW, your `cat` is [unnecessary](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), and for compatibility, it should be `head -n 3`. Not all _head_ implementations understand the `-3` syntax.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If your input text file contains only single words per line, you can do:

```
grep -m 3 -w 'c\w*ee\w*t' file
```

If your input text contains multiple words per line, you could use:

```
grep -m 3 -o -w 'c\w*ee\w*t' file | head -n 3
```

The reason for the need of `head` is that `grep -m NUM` returns `NUM` lines, so if you have multiple matches on a single line, you will have more then `NUM` lines returned (due to `-o`)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
cat words | grep '^c.*ee.*t$' | head -3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU grep, you can use `grep -m` to stop reading a file after a given number of matching lines:

```
grep -m 3 '^c[[:alpha:]]*ee[[:alpha:]]*t$' words
```

`grep` reads files all by itself so there's no need to use `cat` with a pipe.

`[[:alpha:]]` matches alphabet characters, which may be more appropriate than `.*` depending on your input.

I'm also assuming that `words` contains one word per line, otherwise you would be better using the solution with `-o`, `-w` and `head` in [kvantour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64005645/2088135).